# Latex Elsevier template page number on both top and bottom

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering

In [Elsevier template](https://github.com/aignas/LaTeX-project/tree/master/publishing/pub-elsevier/template/crc), there is a problem. It creates page number on both top right and bottom of the page. How should I remove the page number on the bottom?
[image]

```
\documentclass[3p,times,twocolumn,authoryear]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{ecrc}
\volume{00}

\firstpage{1}

\journal{Expert Systems with Applications}

\runauth{Me et al.}

%% The choice of journal logo is determined by the \jid and \jnltitlelogo commands.
%% A user-supplied logo with the name <\jid>logo.pdf will be inserted if present.
%% e.g. if \jid{yspmi} the system will look for a file yspmilogo.pdf
%% Otherwise the content of \jnltitlelogo will be set between horizontal lines as a default logo

%% Give the abbreviation of the Journal.
\jid{eswa}

%% Give a short journal name for the dummy logo (if needed)

%\jnltitlelogo{images/logo/logo-expert-systems-with-applications.gif}
\jnltitlelogo{Expert Systems with Applications}

%% Hereafter the template follows `elsarticle'.
%% For more details see the existing template files elsarticle-template-harv.tex and elsarticle-template-num.tex.



\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}


\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  % \patchcmd{<cmd>}{<search>}{<replace>}{<success>}{<failure>}
  \patchcmd{\MaketitleBox}{\vspace*{-20pt}\fi}{\fi}{}{}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}

\dochead{}

\title{title title title title title title }

\author{author1}
\author{author2}
\author{author3}
\address{address1}
\address{address2}

\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[75]
\end{abstract}

\begin{keyword}
key1,key2,key3,key4,key5,key6
\end{keyword}

\end{frontmatter}

\section{first section}

\lipsum[3-10]


\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num-names}
\bibliography{optimizing_horizon_ref}


\end{document}
```

Comment: You didnt provide a MWE, but `\ofoot{}` should solve the problem.

Comment: @MaestroGlanz, There is a link to github example. I added the code of my example too. what does `\ofoot` do? which package should I load?

Comment: @ar2015: Before removing anything you should consider that `elsevier` put that page number on purpose. If you plan to submit your article etc. to `elsevier` they will probably reject your changes to the layout!

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, What is the purpose of two page number per page? I do not see page number in the bottom of [final versions online](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/journal/09574174).

Comment: Probably because they add custom headers and footers, which overwrite this.

Comment: @ar2015: Well, I don't submit stuff to `elsevier` etc. Ask them about this ;-)

Comment: I read over this link. Apparently, this lorem ipsum. headers and footers are normally divided into three parts: inner foot, center foot, outer foot. Distinguished by their first character (here o). The argument in the `{ }` defines the content. We overwrite it with nothing here, so it is empty.

Comment: I don't think this is the right repository to use. Better use the official files from elsevier.

Comment: @Johannes_B, The official one has the same problem.

Comment: Well then, maybe they want it to be like that? You should asl your editor.